# Notification with inverted color with dark mode

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, android-dark-theme

On android 10, negative images i.e images with inverted color are displayed in the notification from custom-notification apps when dark mode is enabled.

How to prevent that from happening?

Notification with light theme:

[image: image1]

Notification with Dark theme:

[image: image2]

Comment: Hey, did you find any explanation for it?

Comment: No, This doesn't make sense to me. Also, it is happening for only custom notifications, notifications with android-defined templets are fine for both dark and light theme.

Comment: I have the same problem and I can confirm that it is happening on custom notifications with Dark mode enabled. Have anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: No, I have tried many workarounds but failed to fix this.

Comment: i am also facing same issue with custom notification in dark mode.

Comment: any progress ??

Comment: nope, still trying to figure a way.

Comment: it's fixed with me once I updated argetSdkVersion  to be 29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was an android issue, which is fixed after moving to androidx and setting targetsdk to 29 or above.
And to add support for dark mode, we can add the desired color to both the files, color.xml(night) and color.xml(not-night).

Answer (score 0):

same issue on HUAWEI EMUI
if your remoteviews's layout xml has `TextView` Lable and set `android:textColor`
remove it and try again
i dont know why, but this works for me...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was fixed once I updated the `targetSdkVersion` to `29`

`targetSdkVersion 29`

no need to change the textColor of TextView